# Could All Might pass his quirk to multiple people by feeding them his hair?

Tags: my-hero-academia

The quirk that All Might possesses is called All For One. It is a quirk that can be passed from one person to another and it gains more power each time it is passed. All Might gave Deku (Izuku) a sliver of his power by making him eat one of his hairs. If this is how it can be passed than isn't possible for that quirk to be passed to a multitude of people? Say, an army, for example.

Answer (score 5):

All Might himself said:

> After I've given Izuku my hair/DNA, I've gotten a lot weaker

So it would either be a one time thing, or every new user would weaken him substantially so it would still be a small number, and probably of lesser effect.

Comment: I recall that line being a little ambiguous, though. It's likely that passing Deku his power has weakened him, but it could also just have been the progression of his existing degeneration.

Comment: I think he said that after he did it, his strength went down *fast*, so I made that connection, of course it could also be unrelated. Do we have a way to know?

Answer (score 0):

I think yes, all might was already getting weaker as it is but could still give his power off. in the show it made it seem as if 2 people cold hold the quirk at the same time as shown with izuku and all might as there time overlapped. so possibly if we tried passing the quirk among to 2 people it could possibly work.